# custom toolbar after collapsing app bar in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-toolbar, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to create a layout like this:

[image]

where the search view is in a App bar layout. When it is collapsed I want to change the toolbar like this:

[image]

I have searched every where but I was unable to come up with a solution that satisfy me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="375dp"
                android:src="@drawable/yourlogo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_ciew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="#fff"        
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:queryHint="" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Like This]